# How do I deploy a Nuclio function with MLRun?

Tags: nuclio

I need an example of deploying a Nuclio function using MLRun.

- I have my code in a .py file
- How do I use MLRun to deploy this function to Nuclio?
- How do I configure the HTTP endpoint? (using a specified port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow these steps:

1. Call to `code_to_function` as in this example:

```
fn = code_to_function(name='data-generator', handler='main', kind='job', filename='functions/code.py')
```

2. Invoke `with_http` on the function:

```
fn.with_http(host='URL_path', port=port_number)
```

3. Deploy the function:

```
fn.deploy()
```